AWS Step Function Choice State Issue: Glue Job Return Value Not Redirecting as Expected
I have the following scenario:
I need to execute a process in AWS Step Functions that consists of several steps. One of these steps is a Glue Job that validates whether the databases are updated. At the end of the script, I return a condition that will return true or false depending on whether the expected databases are up to date.
I need to use this return value to direct the execution flow in the next step, “updated_databases,” which is a Choice state. If the return value from the previous Glue script is true, I should proceed to the next step, “data_process.” If the return value from the Glue job is false, I should go to the step “end.”
I tried using it like this:
"database_validation_script": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "database_validation",
        "Arguments": {
          "--category.$": "$.Parameters.category",
          "--item.$": "$.Parameters.item",
          "--data_ref.$": "$.Parameters.data_ref",
          "--Year.$": "$.Parameters.Year",
          "--Month.$": "$.Parameters.Month",
          "--Day.$": "$.Parameters.Day"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.base_validation",
      "Next": "updated_databases"
    },
    "updated_databases": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.base_validation.updated_databases",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "data_process"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "end"
    }

But it’s not working. Can someone help me?
Thank you!
Here is my script:
{
  "Comment": "Template for Step Function",
  "StartAt": "GetCurrentDate",
  "States": {
    "GetCurrentDate": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "YearMonth.$": "States.Format('{}{}', States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-'), 0), States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-'), 1))",
        "Year": "States.Format('{}', States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-'), 0))",
        "Month": "States.Format('{}', States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-'), 1))",
        "Day": "States.Format('{}', States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-'), 2))"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.FormattedDate",
      "Next": "parameters_definition"
    },
    "parameters_definition": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "category": "4",
        "item": "1",
        "data_ref": "$.FormattedDate.YearMonth",
        "Year.$": "$.FormattedDate.Year",
        "Month.$": "$.FormattedDate.Month",
        "Day.$": "$.FormattedDate.Day"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.Parameters",
      "Next": "structure_validation_script"
    },
    "structure_validation_script": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "structure_validation",
        "Arguments": {
          "--category.$": "$.Parameters.category",
          "--item.$": "$.Parameters.item",
          "--data_ref.$": "$.Parameters.data_ref",
          "--Year.$": "$.Parameters.Year",
          "--Month.$": "$.Parameters.Month",
          "--Day.$": "$.Parameters.Day"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.Validation",
      "Next": "database_validation_script"
    },
    "database_validation_script": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "database_validation",
        "Arguments": {
          "--category.$": "$.Parameters.category",
          "--item.$": "$.Parameters.item",
          "--data_ref.$": "$.Parameters.data_ref",
          "--Year.$": "$.Parameters.Year",
          "--Month.$": "$.Parameters.Month",
          "--Day.$": "$.Parameters.Day"
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.base_validation",
      "Next": "updated_databases"
    },
    "updated_databases": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.base_validation.updated_databases",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "data_process"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "end"
    },
    "data_process": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "End": true
    },
    "end": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}

Here is the last part of my Python script:
database_validation
validate_databases_by_origin = validate_databases(databases, data_ref)
updated_databases = all([v == 'Updated' for v in validate_databases_by_origin.values()])
print(f'All databases are updated: {updated_databases}')
return updated_databases

And the output is:
True
I’m executing it this way and I’m getting the message:
“Invalid Path ‘$.base_validation.updated_databases’: The choice state’s condition path references an invalid value.”

I think "BooleanEquals": "true" should be "BooleanEquals": true without the quotes around true.

Hey @osekmedia,
Thanks for answer,
My mistake, I accidentally wrote "true" with quotes, but the definition should be without them:
"updated_databases": {
"Type": "Choice",
"Choices": [
{
"Variable": "$.base_validation.updated_databases",
"BooleanEquals": "true",
"Next": "data_process"
}
],
"Default": "end"
}
I’m executing it this way and I’m getting the message:
“Invalid Path ‘$.base_validation.updated_databases’: The choice state’s condition path references an invalid value.”

In your choice try changing "Variable": "$.base_validation.updated_databases" to "Variable": "$.base_validation", I believe you're outputting the result into that variable.

Hey,
I just tested it, and it progressed a bit :) since it didn’t throw an error this time.
It executed without errors and directed to the “end” step.
I’m trying to understand the reason since the return from the Glue job was True, and the validation was set to true.
I changed it to validate as a String and am running it again. I’ll let you know if it works.

You should be able to view the input and output of each step in the console, which may help debug the flow of the stepfunction.

I checked the output there, but it’s not showing the return from the Job. I changed the validation to StringEquals: "True", but the scenario was the same: it executed the Choice step and directed to the End step. I think the object returned by the Glue Job is not being passed to the Step Function.
